# Multiple Records when Importing to Rails via CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import-from-excel

I'm importing some data into my Rails App via CSV. The import works fine, but when I try and insert **contact_name** into the accepted attributes, I get an error:

> unknown attribute 'contact_name' for Hotel

This field does not belong to the hotel, but if it exists on the spreadsheet I need to create a new Contact and assign it to that hotel, during the import.

```
 def self.import(file)

  allowed_attributes = [ "id", "status", "rooms", "country_code", "user_id", "hotel_title","hotel_location", "telephone", "email", "contract_date", "print_date", "created_at","updated_at"]
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|

    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    hotel = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    hotel.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }

    # ASSIGNING VARIABLES
    hotel_name = row["hotel_title"]

    hotel.map = Map.create(:hotel_id => row["id"], :status => 0, :title => "Map Publication for #{hotel_name}")
    hotel.app = App.create(:hotel_id => row["id"], :status => 0, :title => "Bespoke App for #{hotel_name}")
    hotel.save!
  end
end
```

My CSV has 4 columns currently, for simplicity. *hotel_title*, *hotel_location*, *country_code* and *contact_name*.

Comment: What is the relation between `Contact` and `Hotel`?

Answer (score 0):

If the field doesn't exist in the Hotel model, you can't assign it. It will raise an error here

```
hotel.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
```

You must remove it from the allowed attributes, and explicitly compose the Contact if the value is present in the row.

```
if row.to_hash["contact_name"]
  hotel.contact = Contact.new(...)
end
```

The example above assumes you have a `Contact` model associated with `Hotel`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now seeing a different error. (undefined method `contact=') I have updated my original message to show the relevant code.

Comment: You should have created a different question. Now the previous answers will become useless.

Comment: I understand. I have removed that now, but do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a setter method `contact_name=` to do this functionality.

```
#in Hotel

def contact_name=(name)
  contact = self.contacts.find_by_name(name) || self.contacts.build(:name => name)
end
```

because you're doing `build` nothing will be created until the hotel is saved at the end of the update, at which point the contact (if one has been built) will be saved too.